# Python turtle.Screen() not working properly on new Mac. Google has failed me

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I recently got a new computer (Mac 14" Monterey OS) and reinstalled Python, PyCharm, etc. Everything seems to work okay except when running turtle Screen(). The code finishes with exit code 0 (no errors) but when the launcher pops up its just a tiny black screen that flickers. Doesn't even display the title correctly anymore.

It seems I've tried everything: re-installing Python, installing a later version (Python 3.9 vs 3.10) and reinstalling PyCharm, making sure the interpreter is okay. Nothing is working. I've spent about 2 hours googling to find a solution. I'm stuck and frustrated since I am supposed to be doing a coding workthrough with a company this coming week.

Here is the code that should be running:

```
import turtle

screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.title("States Game")
image = "blank_states_img.gif"
screen.addshape(image)

turtle.shape(image)
def get_mouse_click_coor(x, y):
    print(x, y)

turtle.onscreenclick(get_mouse_click_coor)

screen.exitonclick()
```

And here is an image of what is going on...
[please click this link to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMSDY.jpg)

Comment: Just want to bump this question. I get the exact same behavior out of my 14" Mac MBA running Monterey. The 1 "Answer" doesn't resolve my problem, as I'm using Spyder and it's running Python 3.9.5

Answer (score 1):

You need to install Python yourself instead of relying on the Python provided by macOS. I downloaded latest `macOS 64-bit universal2 installer` from https://www.python.org/downloads/macos/ and it works. (make sure you create new interpreter in Pycharm, using the newly installed python)

I think the cause of the issue is that the tkinter package has issues for the builtin python.

Answer (score 0):

Check your python interpreter version.
I have the same issue when it uses python3.8, after upgrading to 3.9. It works perfectly.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You probably update your python version but you didn't change the project Python Interpreter version.

In your IDE:

- Locate Setting
- Go to Project
- Go to Interpreter
- In the Python Interpreter drop do bar, select the most update version of python.

[Image below is the Interpreter setting for PyCharm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oN4ip.png)